# Are these lines correct grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

I want to know if the following lines are grammatically correct. In particular, I want to know if this use of *fell* is correct.

> Dear XXXX:
>   Would you tell me what is the result please?
>   If my question violates your foundation's privacy, fell free to not answering it and I am so sorry for that.
>   Thank you very much.
>   Yours' Sincerely,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the main question, *fell* is the past tense of *fall*, or the present tense of the verb that means:

- to cut down a tree
- to make somebody fall to the ground

Since the next word is *free*, I take you meant "feel free."

As for other things that should be corrected:

- "Yours Sincerely" should be "Yours sincerely" (in British English) or "Sincerely yours" (in American English)
- "Fell free to not answering it and I am so sorry for that." should be "feel free not to answer it. I am sorry for that."
- "Would you tell me what is the result please?" should be "Would you tell me what the result is, please?"

Comment: As for _Your sincerely_ or _Sincerely yours_, I probably couldn't tell you which was British and which was American, so either one could be used. _Yours sincerely_ might sound more novel to this American ear, but it wouldn't throw me off.

Answer (score 5):

1. *Fell* is a typo - it must be *feel*.
2. For the first sentence to be grammatical, we need:

   - Would you tell me what the result is, please?
3. To sound natural, the sentences may be altered to:

   > Dear XXXX: 
   >   Can/Could you please/kindly tell me what the result is? If my question violates your foundation's privacy, feel free **to refrain** from answering it and I am so sorry for asking.

Comment: +1, Sultan, especially for the excellent rewording you made in order to have a more natural phrasing.